# Should current Python projects list `<4` in `python_requires` (setup.py) or not?

Tags: python, setup.py, pypi

I've made a [couple](https://github.com/alastair/python-musicbrainzngs/pull/246) [of](https://github.com/whipper-team/whipper/pull/378) [PRs](https://github.com/MTG/acousticbrainz-client/pull/50) in some projects I'm involved with adding a `python_requires` to their `setup.py` (as per [packaging.python.org/guides/dropping-older-python-versions/](https://packaging.python.org/guides/dropping-older-python-versions/)).

One question that's come up is whether it's a good idea to include `<4` in this statement or not.

On one hand, there's no guarantee that the code will work on Python 4 whenever it comes out (years in the future, probably), but maybe it's also overspecification and would better be left out and added in once Py4 is actually a thing that is even being considered?

I've tried searching for this (including on SO :)), but I'm not getting any good results. Are there are mailing list threads or something that I didn't find that discusses best practices for this? [sampleproject](https://github.com/pypa/sampleproject) includes `<4` but didn't seem to actually discuss this in [the related PR](https://github.com/pypa/sampleproject/pull/87), the [packaging.python.org documentation for `setup_requires`](https://packaging.python.org/guides/distributing-packages-using-setuptools/#python-requires) has examples both with and without the `<4` but doesn't really describe (as far as I can tell) when to include it or not.

Comment: I suggest moving the question to the [Software Engineering](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/) stack exchange. As it stands, this is too opinion based and broad for SO. My too cents is this is not a Python question, but a general question on what you should put on your docs - and generally you do not make mention of future, unreleased languages, that may never see light of day (Python IX?). I would not worry about Python 4 in my docs until it is released, and only than fix what is needed.

Comment: This would be an appropriate question for https://github.com/pypa/packaging-problems/issues, I'd suggest you ask it there, you'll likely get a better response.

Comment: Thanks @DustinIngram! I'll check it out! :)

Comment: See [_Why Python 4.0 won't be like Python 3.0_](https://www.curiousefficiency.org/posts/2014/08/python-4000.html)

Answer (score 0):

> maybe it's also overspecification and would better be left out and added in once Py4 is actually a thing that is even being considered?

Exactly!

The core developers hasn't even started to discuss Python 4, not to say about planning or implementing. They also promised not to break things the way they did with 2-to-3 transition.

With such a distant future and backward compatibility promise it's simply too early to protect yourself from unknown and unplanned breakage. Wait at least until the core developers start to discuss Python 4.